# Trying to loop over DOM nodes, and get the value which is in text format

Tags: javascript

Trying to scrape this site for some data https://steam.tools/itemvalue/#/wowgoldtrader-730

I figured it would be simple with javascript, the script I am trying to make will get all values with:

`let el = document.querySelectorAll('.price');`

And then output the inner text with something like this.

`for(i = 0; i < el.length; i++) { el[i].innerText}`

For some reason the output in the console only gives me the last element price.. if someone see the bug or know why this is not working please let me know

Comment: You are not actually _doing_ anything inside your loop, you are not actively logging anything to the console - so you just get the last value this iterates over shown due to some in-built magic automatism. Make that `console.log(el[i].innerText)` inside your loop, and you will get all of them.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any console log in your for loop. And chrome console would not log every item by itself. Use this snippet:

```
for(i = 0; i < el.length; i++) { console.log(el[i].innerText);}
```

Comment: Thank you this worked, do you by any chance know how I would add all the elements together? and get a single entity value that I can perform calculations on